# How to add carriage return/line feed to an entry being inserted into a CLOB using OCI?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have a column established in my Oracle table that is configured as a CLOB. The purpose of the column is to contain status updates entered by an end user.

I'm successfully adding the updates via PHP/OCI using this code:

```
if (!empty($lastUpdate)) {

$stid5 = oci_parse($connect, "UPDATE service_status SET ss_update_details = '$lastUpdate' || ss_update_details WHERE ss_id = $tableID");

$r = oci_execute($stid5);

}
```

You'll note I'm using a concatenation approach to add the updates to the column, so many updates can exist in the column.

When I retrieve the data for viewing using this PHP/OCI code in a HTML page...

```
$stid1 = oci_parse($connect, "SELECT * FROM service_status WHERE ss_id = $tableID");

$r = oci_execute($stid1);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid1, OCI_BOTH+OCI_RETURN_LOBS))!= false)
    {
        echo '<h3>Last Update Time and Action Taken:</h3>
        <p>'.$row['SS_UPDATE_DETAILS'].'</p>';
    }
```

...the results are bundled together, with no carriage return or line feed in between entries. Not visually pleasing...expected behavior, I know.

My question is: How can I add a line feed/carriage return to the end of each entry in order to make reading the contents of the CLOB more "user friendly"?

I've tried adding the letter Z as a "dummy" character to my UPDATE statement, like this...

```
UPDATE service_status SET ss_update_details = '$lastUpdate Z' || ss_update_details WHERE ss_id = $tableID"
```

...then coupled that with a modified SELECT statement using TRANSLATE...

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(ss_update_details, 'Z', CHR(10)) FROM service_status WHERE ss_id = $tableID"
```

This resulted in no rows being returned. Not sure if the oci_fetch_array I'm using is happy with my TRANSLATE attempt?

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Littlefoot for providing guidance. In order to see my CLOB records show up on a HTML page with line breaks in between, I concatenated the `<br />` tag to each record being updated, like this:

```
UPDATE service_status SET ss_update_details = '$lastUpdate' || '<br />' || ss_update_details WHERE ss_id = $tableID"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenating CHR(10)? Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (col clob);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into test (col) values
  2    ('$lastUpdate on ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi') || chr(10) ||
  3     '- updated by   ' || 'Littlefoot'                || chr(10) ||
  4     '- while anwering the question on StackOverflow' || chr(10) ||
  5     'The End'
  6    );

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$lastUpdate on 18:34
- updated by   Littlefoot
- while anwering the question on StackOverflow
The End


SQL>
```

Comment: Ahhh. So, I should use INSERT with the concatenation symbol instead of my UPDATE approach? For some reason, I was thinking that INSERT would overwrite what's already in my CLOB (which I don't want).

Comment: Oh, no - update is OK; it's just that ma table was empty so I did an insert. You'd update, just "copy" what & how I used the CHR(10).

Comment: I modified my UPDATE statement to reflect "UPDATE service_status SET ss_update_details = '$lastUpdate' || chr(10) || ss_update_details WHERE ss_id = $tableID". However, I'm still not seeing the line break between records when I publish the result in HTML using oci_fetch_array.

Comment: I know nothing about *oci_fetch_array*. However, if it is HTML, would replacing CHR(10) with <br> do any good?

Comment: Hmmm...now THAT's an interesting idea. I could possibly do a TRANSLATE to change the chr(10) into a <br> tag. Let me give that a try.